# How to remove duplicate parameters in a playbook?

Tags: ansible

Given that I have a role name `postgres` that runs locally and has this definition of `roles/postgres/tasks/main.yml`

```
- name: Ping
  postgresql_ping:
    login_host: localhost
    login_user: postgres
    login_password: postgres
    db: postgres

- name: Create database
  postgresql_db:
    login_host: localhost
    login_user: postgres
    login_password: postgres
    name: newdb
    encoding: UTF-8

- name: Drop database
  postgresql_db:
    login_host: localhost
    login_user: postgres
    login_password: postgres
    name: newdb
    state: absent
```

Is there a way for me to reduce that by moving the parameters `login_host`, `login_user`, and `login_password` somewhere else so wherein I use the `postgressql` galaxy collection, it will always connect to the same database instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postgres modules ultimately use the [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq.html) library, which means you can use any of the [standard environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html). That means you should be able to write your playbook like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
  - community.postgres
  environment:
    PGHOST: localhost
    PGUSER: postgres
    PGPASSWORD: secret
  tasks:
  - name: Ping
    postgresql_ping:

  - name: Create database
    postgresql_db:
      name: newdb
      encoding: UTF-8

  - name: Drop database
    postgresql_db:
      name: newdb
      state: absent
```

Absent explicit configuration in each task, the modules will use the values from the `PG*` environment variables.

---

There are three places you can set environment variabeles in Ansible:

1. At the playbook level, as demonstrated above.
2. At the task level:

   ```
   - postgresl_ping:
     environment:
       PGHOST: localhost
       PGUSER: postgres
       PGPASSWORD: secret
   ```
3. Outside of your playbook:

   ```
   PGHOST=localhost PGUSER=postgres PGPASSWORD=secret \
   ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
   ```

If you execute roles using `import_role` or `include_role`, you can use option 2, above, to set per-role environment variables:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
  - community.postgres
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: postgres
      environment:
        PGHOST: localhost
        PGUSER: postgres
        PGPASSWORD: secret
```

Comment: Is there a way to define `environment` at the `<role>/tasks/main.yml` file instead if adding it to the playbook file? I'd like to have a common playbook to be executed not just for Postgres.